# Break out with css grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Following a technique described [in this blog post](https://rachelandrew.co.uk/archives/2017/06/01/breaking-out-with-css-grid-explained/) I tried to make a css grid where my images will be wider than the centered text column. However, I can't make it work and I am unsure why.

My HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<main class="grid">
  <div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum [...]</p>

    <p class="full"><a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x250"></a></p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum [...]</p>
  </div>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

And the css:

```css
img {
    width: 100%;
}

.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    grid-auto-rows: 150px;
    grid-template-columns: 
        [full-start] minmax(1em,1fr)
        [main-start] minmax(0, 40em) [main-end]
        minmax(1em,1fr) [full-end];
}

.grid > * {
  grid-column: main ;
}

.full {
  grid-column: full;
}
```

This renders on my machine (Google Chrome, Windows) to this screenshot where the image is not stretched to the full width:

[image: Image not breaking out grid]

I'd like to get this working first, as I aim to have a three-width layout: full width, wide and text (main) width:

```
|     |      | text width |      |      |
|     |      | text width |      |      |
|     |                          |      |
|     |  ---   image width  ---  |      |
|     |                          |      |
|     |      | text width |      |      |
|     |      | text width |      |      |
|                                       |
|  ---------   full width    ---------  |
|                                       |
|     |      | text width |      |      |
|     |      | text width |      |      |
```

For a start, I was hoping full width / text width was possible and after that I'd extend it with a third width (in above "image width").

Did I simply make a typo which I can't find or is this mistake somewhere else?

Comment: Your .full image is not a direct child of the grid, only it's parent div is a grid-item. Make sure that the image is outside of the div (so that it's a direct child of main.grid) and it should behave like you expect it.

Answer (score 2):

Grid properties affect *grid items* which are direct child elements of the *grid container* (this is similar to a flexbox). Here you have an extra `div` wrapper inside the `main` grid container - remove this:

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-auto-rows: 150px;
  grid-template-columns: [full-start] minmax(1em, 1fr) [main-start] minmax(0, 40em) [main-end] minmax(1em, 1fr) [full-end];
}

.grid>* {
  grid-column: main;
}

.full {
  grid-column: full;
}
```

```html
<main class="grid">
  <!-- <div> -->
    <p>Lorem ipsum [...]</p>

    <p class="full">
      <a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x250"></a>
    </p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum [...]</p>
  <!-- </div> -->
</main>
```

Now your image exceeds its container - you can use `object-fit` on the image - see modified demo:

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; /* added */
  object-fit: cover; /* added */
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-auto-rows: 150px;
  grid-template-columns: [full-start] minmax(1em, 1fr) [main-start] minmax(0, 40em) [main-end] minmax(1em, 1fr) [full-end];
}

.grid>* {
  grid-column: main;
}

.full {
  grid-column: full;
}
```

```html
<main class="grid">
  <!-- <div> -->
    <p>Lorem ipsum [...]</p>

    <p class="full">
      <a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x250"></a>
    </p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum [...]</p>
  <!-- </div> -->
</main>
```